# $E$ Banach space, $K: E \to E$ compact $\Rightarrow$ if $\lambda \neq 0 \in \sigma(K)$, $\lambda$ is eigenvalue

Tags: proof-verification, spectral-theory, compact-operators

First denote by $\mathcal F(E)$ the set of all Fredholm operators mapping from $E \to E$; the *index* $\operatorname{ind} := \operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{ker}T) - \operatorname{dim}(E / T(E)$. We know that $\operatorname{ind}: \mathcal F(E) \to \mathbb Z $  is continuous and thus the sets $\mathcal F_k(E) := \{T \in \mathcal F(E): \operatorname{ind} T = k\}$ are open and mutually disjoint $\forall k \in \mathbb Z$.

I would argue as follows: Let $\lambda \neq 0 \in \sigma(K)$. First consider $I - {1 \over \lambda}K$ which has the same range and kernel as $\lambda I - K$.
Then, $\{t \in [0,1]: \operatorname{ind}(I - t{1 \over \lambda}K)\}$ is path-connected and hence connected. But we know that $\operatorname{ind}$ is constant on each connected component and hence $\operatorname{ind}(I - {1 \over \lambda}K) = \operatorname{ind}(I) = 0$. Thus $\lambda I - K$ is injective if and only if it's surjective ($\star$).

By assumption $\lambda I - K$ is not bijective (otherwise by the Open Mapping Theorem, its inverse would be in $L(E)$). But then by ($\star$) it's not injective and thus $\operatorname{ker}(\lambda I - K) \setminus \{0\} \neq \varnothing$.

Anything to add?

Comment: I think you are missing something. The set $\{t \in [0,1] : \text{ind} (I- t \frac{1}{\lambda}K) \}$ is unclear, could you clarify what you meant?

Comment: @S.Dewar You are kinda right. I meant $\{t \in [0,1]: (I - t{1 \over \lambda}K)\} \subset \mathcal F(E)$ is connected in $\mathcal F(E)$ and we know that $\operatorname{ind}$ is constant on each connected component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is correct, however I would note that $$ \left\{t \in [0,1]: \text{ind} \left(I−t\frac{1}{λ}K \right)\right\} $$ is not standard notation for what you mean (which I assume is the straight line from $I$ to $(I-\frac{1}{\lambda}T)$); what you should write is $$ \left\{ \text{ind} \left(I−t\frac{1}{λ}K \right) : t \in [0,1] \right\} .$$ This is standard notation as far as I know but if there is any reference you have of it being different I would be interested in seeing it.

Comment: you are right, that was a bit sloppy by me

Comment: In fact it is supposed to be $\{(I - t{1 \over \lambda}K):t \in [0,1]\} \subset \mathcal F (E)$